# git push is very slow for a merely small change

Tags: git, android-source, gerrit, jgit

I have a big clone of AOSP `platform/frameworks/base`, and a private git server serve it.
Here is its charastics

1. 300k refs on server side, 3k refs on local side
2. 5G of total size

and the characstic of google pure aosp repo is

1. 100k refs on server side, 1300 refs on local side
2. 3.5G of total size

But when i just change one letter of the repo and try to push to server. it take 1 minute, and accroding to `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE`, it spends 44 seconds on `git pack-objects`.
What is it doing?

Here is trace of my local repo

```
GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 git push ssh://cy@localhost:6650/home/cy/Documents/Codes/base.git HEAD:bsp-umi-r
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 6.02 KiB | 2.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
21:03:24.373799 trace.c:475             performance: 44.742570511 s: git command: /usr/lib/git-core/git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress
```

And here is google pure aosp gerrit push trace

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 345 bytes | 345.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
20:51:05.746853 trace.c:475             performance: 0.054018553 s: git command: /usr/lib/git-core/git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
20:51:06.574086 trace.c:475             performance: 0.894403495 s: git command: /usr/lib/git-core/git send-pack --stateless-rpc --helper-status --thin --progress https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/ --stdin
To https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
```

Where can make such differences where google project only takes 0.05 seconds to push one change and i have to take 44 seconds?

Comment: Have you considered asking the admin of that private git server?

Comment: I'm the admin :)

Comment: So, what's the bottleneck on the server? Disk access to the repo? CPU? Paging? If it's CPU then Git might be the problem but you haven't eliminated some obvious possibilities here.

Comment: There no bottleneck on server. the actual bottleneck is on local side, the CPU runs 100% for 44 seconds by `git pack-objects` while google only take 0.05 seconds. i use exactly same git for both repositories

Comment: Okay, you did say push and I just skipped right past that, sorry. So, where is it slow, it shows you four stages, enumerate, count, compress, write. Watch it. Find what objects it's sending. Look at the objects.

Comment: Compressing objects is in general slow, as Git will spend as much CPU as you let it on finding good deltas. You can limit how much compression Git does using various configuration knobs (look for `pack.*` items). Note that you'll trade faster-but-worse-compression for more-network-traffic to send the less-compressed data. If the faster compression takes 1 second instead of 44 seconds, and the extra network traffic adds 2 more seconds, that's a good tradeoff. :-)

Comment: the problem is i didn't find any special config between google repo and mine. After all, clone to local will reset all repo-based configuration of git

Comment: @torek i think you may notice that the final data is just 345 bytes. i don't think compress 345 bytes data can take 44 seconds.

Comment: It's not compressing 345 bytes, it's compressing *to* 345 bytes. It took 44 seconds to figure out that it could do so. That time involved looking at potentially every object in the repository: 5 GB of data. That's where all the time goes, reading and checking all the *potential* ways of compressing the data; that's where you need to inform Git: *do less here*.

Comment: Let's say, for argument sake, that Git spent 44 seconds looking at all 5 GB of data, and that by setting up multi-pack index files, setting pack.* variables, and setting up other such things, you can get Git to spend only 1 or 2 seconds looking at only 500 kB of data and the end result is compressing to 91834 bytes instead of 345 bytes. You then send those ~100kbytes in 2 seconds instead of 0 seconds. Your total time is now about 4 seconds. Look how much network bandwidth you wasted! But overall, that was good.

Comment: @demonguy since you are the admin I am assuming you have access to the server where the git repository is hosted. You might want to check the status of your repository. They might need to be garbage collected. You can use [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) and the [git-count-objects](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-count-objects) command to check the status of your repository on disk.